# Brew can't change mysql password

Tags: mysql, macos, homebrew

Im installing mysql on my MacOS with the [following tutorial](https://gist.github.com/nrollr/3f57fc15ded7dddddcc4e82fe137b58e) and completing everything I'm facing the problem while changing the password:

> Open Terminal and execute the following command to set the root password:
>   `mysqladmin -u root password 'yourpassword'`

so I'm typing it and I see the error:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
```

So I thought maybe my mysql service is not running:

```
$ brew services list
```

but it is:

```
Admin-MacBook-Pro:log sandra$ brew services list
Name     Status  User         Plist
mysql    started sandra /Users/sandra/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

so maybe mysql.sock file is missing? no, it is and its named as `/tmp/mysql.sock.lock`. So where could be the problem? I tried everything googling the problem.

Comment: brew services restart mysql

Comment: tried many times already

Comment: look in mysql's log files to see what the startup error is.

Answer (score 0):

It may be running as a process, not a service.

Try running the following in terminal:

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

If you see the process running, then you are locked out. Try killing the process:

```
kill -9 {pid}
```

Then:

```
/pathToMySQL/mysql.server start
```

Once it is restarted, try connecting again.

Comment: `Admin-MacBook-Pro:log sandra$ ps aux | grep mysql
sadra     19903   0.0  0.0  2434852    824 s001  S+    8:02PM   0:00.00 grep mysql` so its running? how to kill it? and how to know path tho mysql?

Comment: It appears it only returned the results from the grep search itself. Try running the mysql.server start command